# setting opacity for ion-label of disabled ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic4

In my ionic application of Ionic V4, I want to set the `ion-label` text color as black of `ion-input` which is disabled.

[image]

Anyhow I got the value text color of disabled `ion-input` black by using the adding following CSS code in my `global.scss`.

```
.native-input[disabled] {
    opacity: 10 !important;
}
```

Also want the same for `ion-label` of disabled `ion-input`.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the same problem by putting the following into the scss file for the page:

```
ion-label {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can easily solve it by using

**[readonly]="true"**
instead of
**disabled**

```
<input ... [readonly]="true" value="read-only input" ...>
```

OR just **readonly**, like this :

```
<input ... readonly value="read-only input" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

For ionic 5 this works for me in the scss of the page, without `!important`:

```
.item-interactive-disabled ion-label {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing somthing like this:

```
.native-input:disabled{
   opacity:10 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in global.scss

```css
.native-input[disabled].sc-ion-input-md {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```